# Specify file encoding when using QGIS Split vector layer

Tags: qgis, splitting, encoding

I've successfully split a shapefile into multiple shapefiles using the "Split vector layer" tool (Vector > Data Management Tools) in QGIS 3.16.15-Hannover. However, The split shapefiles always use the system's encoding. According to the manual, [file encoding can be changed in the "Output directory" parameter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer), but I can't find any option to change the encoding there.

[image: Split vector layer]

How can I specify file encoding for split shapefiles?

Comment: I ended up using the "Split Table/Shapes by Attribute" tool in SAGA GIS 2.3.2 to split my shapefile instead. Not sure if it used the same file encoding as the original shapefile or used UTF-8 as the default file encoding.

Comment: I could not find the promised file encoding setting either.